# std::vector pushing speed?

Tags: c++, performance, containers

I'm using vector to manage my large structure data. But suddenly, when discovering `vector` source code, I am very surprised to see some code below :

```
inline void push_back(const _Ty& _X)
    {insert(end(), _X); }
//...

void insert(iterator _P, size_type _M, const _Ty& _X)
    {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        iterator _S = allocator.allocate(_N, (void *)0);
        iterator _Q = _Ucopy(_First, _P, _S);
        _Ufill(_Q, _M, _X);
        _Ucopy(_P, _Last, _Q + _M);
        _Destroy(_First, _Last);
        allocator.deallocate(_First, _End - _First);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

It's the snippet code which **"destroys"** then **reallocates** its whole vector data. It's so annoying, because my structure has a large size and a vector has to manage hundreds of elements, while I only use `vector::operator []` and `vector::push_back()`, especially **`pushing back`** takes most of my program time (it's time-consuming). In my case, is there any better container which can perform faster than `std::vector`, while I tried to google but no luck?

Comment: have a look at `std::vector::reserve`

Comment: If you are calling `push_back()` will iterating over a range you can use `v.insert(v.end(), input.begin(), input.end())` instead which will reduce the number of allocations.

Comment: Think of a vector as a wrapper for an array. Once you run out of space in the array you need to create a bigger array, copy elements over, and delete the old array.

Comment: The `insert` overload you cite isn't the one `push_back` calls (two arguments vs. three)! `push_back` has amortized O(1) time complexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The allocate-copy-delete (or allocate-move-delete in C++11) only happens once each time the vector exceeds its current *capacity.* With each such reallocation, the capacity doubles. This averages out over time, so the *amortized complexity* of [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is constant.

You can pre-allocate the vector's capacity by using its [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) member function.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the capacity doubles. This makes the number of reallocations only log2(n)

Comment: Except that the capacity doesn't necessarily double. It just has to increase in some exponential form, so that the number of reallocations is logX(n), where X is the growth factor. In MSVC's standard library, it's 1.6, not 2.

Comment: That's how it amortizes, really. Each element only does 3 (a constant number) units of work: push_back itself; copy itself in next reallocation; copy its left-half counterpart in next reallocation. After that, it ends up in the left half of the vector, and will be "paid for" by the right-half elements in further reallocations.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Fair enough, but it's generally easier to understand and visualise this with doubling. A different rate of growth is just a generalisation after that.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: actually, even though it's not implement, even a constant factor is not necessary. One could perfectly imagine switching to smaller and smaller factors as the number of elements grow in order to reduce the "waste". I think that all that matters is that asymptotically the factor is `> 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Would [reserving](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) all the space you need before adding elements solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Reallocation only occurs if your vector size increases past its capacity. If you know in advance (even roughly) how many items your vector will contain, you can use its [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) member to pre-allocate enough capacity. You can also trigger reallocation yourself in a controlled manner, even while filling the vector, to reduce the number of times it is called and thus get better performance.

Now if you want guaranteed constant-time insertion there are containers that can be used for that but at a trade-off (eg. `std::list` will allocate lots of small memory blocks which may end up not any faster that your current vector use, because `new` is quite slow, and the memory usage will be more important too, and you lose random access, but sure *every* insertion will take roughly the same time as the others).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your final data size, you can use `reserve` to preallocate the memory needed for the vector.  That will remove all reallocating and copying.

If you don't know the exact size, make an educated guess based on what you do know about your incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is a dynamically expanding container, but its contents are required to be in a contiguous block of memory (as I recall, this was unspecified in pre-C++11 but everybody did it).  So if your vector already holds 8 elements, and the current capacity of the vector is 8 elements, then when you push_back a 9th element, the container must allocate new space for the larger capacity, copy the 8 elements that are already in the container, copy the 9th element into the new space, then destroy the old.   If you are using C++11, and your elements support move-construction, then the 8 copies can become 8 moves.  Or if you want to incur the overheads of managing pointers, you could store pointers to elements instead of elements (copying a pointer is cheap, but now you need to deal with the lifespan issue).

As for which container is faster than vector, that's a large open-ended question.  It depends on all sorts of access/manipulation patterns.   std::list was mentioned as a candidate.  O(1) adding to the end of the list, but is probably a bigger O(1) than the amortized O(1) that vector uses.  You lose random-access into the container.

Answer (score -1):

Yes `push_back()` is known to be constant most of time, but needs to re-allocate the whole vector when the `size()` reach the `capacity()`.

If you want constant time insertion, you must try a `std::list` or a `std::deque`. Especially a `std::deque` provides correct performance for insertion at the end of your container while being close to a vector in its interface.

Extract from [cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/):

> Therefore they provide a similar functionality as vectors, but with efficient insertion and deletion of elements also at the beginning of the sequence, and not only at its end. But, unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations, thus not allowing direct access by offsetting pointers to elements.

Comment: `vector` is amortized constant time, and that is still constant time. The difference in `std::list` is that it's still constant time adding to the middle or end, and `std::deque` to the beginning, which is what that quote is discussing.

Comment: "vector is amortized constant time, and that is still constant time." I am aware of all that thank you :-), while my post tries to be concise and not detail everything, I fail to see how it contradicts with what a list or a vector does.

Comment: Not a contradiction, but I downvoted because the extract is unrelated to the question. It's talking about the inserting at the beginning. And you said "If you want constant time insertion, you must try a std::list or a std::deque", implying that `vector` does not suffice. That is a contradiction.

Comment: So if you agree with my point, why mention the other containers at all?

Comment: I was specifying "constant time insertion" as opposed to "amortized constant time insertion". Sorry but my post is an attempt to provide a solution for the op. I still feel it as valuable so I won't modify it nor delete it. :-)

Comment: I do not agree with your points: deque is ok for insertion in the end as specified in the quote. And for the other point the balance between conciseness and detail vocabulary (in the "constant time" issue) does not invalidate my post. The op is asking for other container in its question therefore I propose.